# Which text editors handle both Windows- and Unix-style line breaks properly?

Tags: text-editor, newline

Which text editors (free or commercial) handle character encoding and  Windows/Unix line breaks properly?

Answer (score 16):

[Here's a list of Text editors and their newline support.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Newline_support)

Also see [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Basic_features) and look at the Newline conversion field

Comment: Nice! This looks quite useful.

Comment: I noticed that according to that link the MS DOS editor supports all types, while notepad (which I suppose you could call the windows editor) only supports 1. Crazy.

Comment: MS-Dos editor support is as so. "Editor converts Unix newlines to DOS newlines"

Answer (score 5):

I should think the vast majority do. Certainly [Vim](http://www.vim.org) and [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) will.

Answer (score 4):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) is free and handles this dandily. Not to mention it's quite handy for plenty of other text-editing tasks.

Answer (score 1):

[textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) does a good job. i like version 4.7 it is much nicer than 5.*

Comment: I like it too - it has neat regular expression search and replace built into it (not as strong as the unix one though)

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is really good.

Answer (score 1):

[Scintilla and Scite](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) are my favorites but there are lots of good ones that will do what you want

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use PowerShell ISE for editing files with Unix line breaks.

The only side-effect I observed is that you have to set "Save as type" to "All files" on "Save As..." command to avoid appending .ps1 file extension.

Comment: A good thing about  PS ISE is that it presents in windows servers out-of-box. This allows manual tweaks in RDP without set up redundant tools.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any that does not. I do not count notepad.exe.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) also does a great job between reformatting between windows and Unix. Additionally as mentioned before, Emacs is great too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having no problems whatsoever with formatting, special characters and umlauts by using [IDM UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads.html).

Answer (score 0):

[jEdit](http://jedit.org/) does it.