# Looping and grep writes output for the last line only

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am looping through the lines in a text file. And performing grep on each lines through directories. like below

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
 echo "This is the field: $p"
  grep -ilr $p * >> Result.txt
done < fields.txt
```

But the above writes the results for the last line in the file. And not for the other lines.

If i manually execute the command with the other lines, it works (which mean the match were found). Anything that i am missing here? Thanks

The fields.txt looks like this

```
annual_of_measure__c
attached_lobs__c
apple
```

Comment: Shouldn't `||` be `&&` ?

Comment: the looping part works.

Comment: Can you show us an extract from `fields.txt`

Comment: updated the OP.

Comment: The result.txt have the list of file names that has the string. And i am expecting the results like this for all the fields/lines in the fields.txt.

Comment: Just an idea: is the fields.txt file from DOS with DOS lineendings and no newline in the last line? Can you check if the lineendings are unix lineendings?

Comment: man, i think thats the answer... i remember encountering something like this before. i will check and confirm

Comment: that was it @LarsFischer.  Please update the answer and i will accept it

Comment: If you fix fields.txt to use linefeeds instead of linefeed/carriage-return pairs as line endings, you won't need the `|| [ -n "$p" ]` hack anymore either.

Comment: @OK999 I tried to give a good explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file `fields.txt`

1. has DOS/Windows lineending convention consisting of two character (Carriage-Return AND Linefeed) and
2. that file is processed by Unix-Tools expecting Unix lineendings consisting of only one character (Linefeed)

then the line read by the `read` command and stored in the variable `$p` is in the first line `annual_of_measure__c\r` (note the additional `\r` for the Carriage-Return). Then grep will not find a match.

From your description in the question and the confirmation in the comments, it seems that the last line in `fields.txt` has no lineending at all, so the variable `$p` is the ordinary string `apple` and grep can find a match on the last line of the file.

There are tools for converting lineendings, e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23210535/4086774) or [even more options in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/4086774).

Comment: The above explanation is spot on. I am using a pc and the file have the DOS lineending convention. The same file is process in a bash shell (git bash on windows). i used the dos2unix executable to convert the file.