# Filter a file using a column value greater than a number (awk not working)

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to filter a file using values in the 8 column >= 10. I am using awk but for some reason it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong, what am I missing?

```
head df_TPM.csv
LQNS02136402.1_14821_3p,12680.71611,11346.42368,11686.28693,9067.797819,7429.467928,5551.660333,3246.956281
LQNS02000137.1_325_3p,8342.540984,5905.726173,4503.363041,3616.191278,3142.965662,3678.829299,6288.621969
LQNS02278148.1_40791_3p,4921.502758,2461.882836,429.824973,261.273116,132.0239748,68.6191655,70.8815385
LQNS02278089.1_34112_3p,4246.71324,4584.529009,8687.922574,7570.83746,5801.384953,2870.020801,734.3131465
LQNS02278075.1_32377_5p,4143.547577,4093.91803,10804.12323,10062.99269,7925.240969,4712.484455,1080.915573
LQNS02138569.1_14892_3p,2668.27957,2160.173542,837.2584183,233.2310273,84.62362925,64.6037895,23.456714
LQNS02278075.1_32324_5p,2331.608924,491.8868983,1527.312199,881.8683105,747.1474225,347.397634,74.07259175
LQNS02278075.1_32382_3p,2140.686095,2439.122353,10837.38169,12569.95295,9385.530878,6022.323737,1705.900969
LQNS02000138.1_777_5p,1819.275149,1762.009649,8565.396754,33280.90019,32176.07604,15849.37306,11872.99383
LQNS02278186.1_47223_3p,1687.843418,728.4288968,1328.048172,1306.424238,2102.27342,14.78892225,9.92647375

#Extract column 1 and 8 and print if $8>=10
cat df_TPM.csv |awk -F"," '{print $1, $8}' | grep -E "^LQN" | awk -F " " '$2>= 10'

LQNS02276925.1_23356_5p 5.352369
LQNS02277221.1_25158_5p 2.82778125
LQNS02277812.1_29775_3p 11.1090745
LQNS02278074.1_32154_3p 6.124789
LQNS02278139.1_39525_5p 22.6656355

#As you can see lots of numbers shouldn't be there (ex: 2.82778125 < 10)
```

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/SzLsIL, it looks fine if you just use `awk '$2 >= 10'` on your data.

Comment: Well, actually, `awk -F"," '/^LQN/ && $8 >= 10 {print $1, $8}' df_TPM.csv` should work for you. See https://ideone.com/LSBRGY

Comment: why so many "pipes"? ```awk -F, '/^LQN/ && $8>=10 {print $1,$8}' df_TPM.csv```

Comment: Because I am bad, you are right. But still prints things with values < 10. Can my awk be wrong? 9.99 does work fine, but any number greater than 10 is problematic.

Comment: What if you do `$8+0 >= 10`? `awk -F"," '/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10 {print $1, $8}' df_TPM.csv`?

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, works fine for me for your sample file: getting 9 lines out of 10; skipping the one with ```9.92647375```. Do you have ^M-s in the file?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that seems to work. I don't understand what's wrong with my awk or file

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios, your code works for me, could you please check once `cat -v file` if you have any control M characters in your Input_file once?

Comment: @vgersh99 is almost certainly correct and the problem is DOS line endings causing $8 to end in `^M` and so not look like a number to awk. You can verify that by doing a numeric comparison with any other field than the last one on the line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment97778025_45772525 for how to deal with that.

Comment: @vgersh99  that was the problem indeed. Solved using the dos2unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your `awk` to coerce `$8` into a number by computing `$8+0`. It is recommended that you ensure you have GNU awk installed to avoid issues. Also, you may probably [use `dos2unix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210500/how-to-use-dos2unix/23210535) before working on the files to normalize the line endings.

The whole command can be written as

```sh
awk -F"," '/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10 {print $1, $8}' df_TPM.csv
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/LSBRGY).

**NOTE**: To only **count these lines**, use
The whole command can be written as

```sh
awk -F, '/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10 {cnt++} END{print cnt}' df_TPM.csv
```

To find the lines that do not start with `LQN`, just add the negation operator `!` before `/^LQN/`:

```sh
awk -F, '!/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10 {cnt++} END{print cnt}' df_TPM.csv
```

**Details**

- `-F","` (= `-F,`) - set the field separator to a comma
- `/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10` - if the current line starts with `LQN` and the eighth field is equal or larger than `10`
- `!/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10` - if the current line does not start with `LQN` and the eighth field is equal or larger than `10`
- `{print $1, $8}` - print Field 1 and 8
- `{cnt++}` - increment the `cnt` variable
- `END{print cnt}` - print the `cnt` variable once the `awk` finishes processing lines.

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed awk would know that was a number. That was super useful!

Comment: Also I had to write it like this ```grep -e "^LQN" df_TPM.csv | awk -F, '$8+0 >= 10 {print $1,$8}'| wc -l``` because i also want to get the ones that don't start with LQN and i know how to do that with grep -v but not with awk

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios I understand `gawk` does understand that since you have seen the [previous test](https://ideone.com/SzLsIL) using your code. You must have some other version.

Comment: Thanks, awk version 20070501

Comment: With `awk`, you just use `awk -F, '!/^LQN/ && $8+0 >= 10 {print $1, $8}' file | wc -l`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know i could use ! in awk too.

Comment: If you need to add `0` to that then the version of awk you are running is broken and you should find a new one because other things may also be broken that you haven't encountered yet. I suspect instead that [@vgersh99 is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522666/filter-a-file-using-a-column-value-greater-than-a-number-awk-not-working#comment115842223_65522666) and you have control-Ms in your file and doing the `+0` is just working around that problem manifesting because the number you're interested in is at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

By seeing OP's comment, in case you don't want to search for `LQN` text in starting of line and want to check if 8th column is greater than 10 then try following(to check if lines have `LQN` remove `!` from following codes).

```
awk -F"," '$8+0 >= 10 && !/^LQN/{print $1, $8}' df_TPM.csv
```

OR To get total lines try: counting those matched lines could be done in a single `awk` itself.

```
awk -F"," '$8+0 >= 10 && !/^LQN/{count++} END{print count}' df_TPM.csv
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F"," '               ##Starting awk program from here.
$8+0 >= 10 && !/^LQN/{    ##Checking condition if 8th field is greater than 10 and NOT LQN.
  count++                 ##Increasing count with 1 here.
}
END{                      ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  print count             ##Printing count value here.
}
' df_TPM.csv              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

To handle control M characters in `awk` code itself try: considering that you don't want control M characters in your Input_file.

```
awk -F"," '{gsub(/\r/,"")} $8 >= 10 && !/^LQN/{count++} END{print count}' df_TPM.csv
```