# /usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, git-bash, docker-for-windows

I'm new to Docker and i decided to take the beginners guide on [Play with docker classroom (Application Containerization and Microservice Orchestration)](https://training.play-with-docker.com/microservice-orchestration/). I tried this tutorial on my PC and installing docker for windows. In [Step 1: Containerized Link Extractor Script](https://training.play-with-docker.com/microservice-orchestration/#step-1-containerized-link-extractor-script) on running the script `docker container run -it --rm linkextractor:step1 http://example.com/` I'm getting an error

`IT-KEVIN@IT-KEVIN MINGW64 ~/linkextractor (step1)
$ docker container run -it --rm linkextractor:step1 http://example.com/
/usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory`

How can i fix the error?

Comment: @usr2564301 oh sorry about posting images of text. Yes, but i already switch my docker to linux containers. Still getting the error.

Comment: It seems your Python cannot be located. Did you try something like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/942930/usr-bin-env-python-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @usr2564301 i already point the exact path of my python. When i try to run `python -version i get `$ python --version
Python 3.7.6`. still no luck

Answer (score 0):

`\r` character is is usually a sign that you have mixed [different newline formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) in your editor.

You need yo edit the `linkextractor` script and fix its newlines to Linux format.

Comment: Here's the script.  Where would be newline?                                                                                       
                                                                                                                            `#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get(sys.argv[-1])
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
`

Comment: Here some pointer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001900/which-text-editors-handle-both-windows-and-unix-style-line-breaks-properly